# Regex Expression Query

Tags: regex, expression

I have data as

```
CVE-2011-0573,
CVE-2011-0606,
(CVE-2011-0565)
CVE-2011-0598,
CVE-2011-0593.
((CVE-2011-0593.)
```

Could you please help me writing RegEx so I only get `ABC-####-####` ? The last four digit may vary, so it can have e.g. three or five digits, but most likely not more than ten. Also the expresion may contain some spaces in the end, so those need to be removed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for matching:

```
[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3,10}
```

If you have `multiline` flag available then use

```
/^[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3,10}$/mg
```

Comment: should be `{3,10}`, or maybe just `{1,10}`

Comment: Thanks, I edited, yes `[0-9]{,10}` OR `[0-9]+` would have been fine too.

Comment: That was fast, thanks a lot. Works great. Btw is it possible to write the same RegEx so it catches up the unwanted characters? So e.g. for "CVE-2011-0573," the RegEx returns "," and so on.

Comment: This regex will match `CVE-2011-0573` discarding comma after it. Why do you need comma to be captured?

Comment: I am using one Script in my SSIS.. it works in the way it finds the unwanted chars and only removes them .. so if I use your ReGex, the script in SSIS return the unwanted chars only which is the opposite of my goal. So if its not possible, I will try to edit the script in SSIS somehow.

Comment: I am still not clear what you want me to change. Do you want to capture comma also that comes after string? I cannot understand your script since this answer is pure regex based.

Comment: I am using C# code at this site http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.cz/2011/03/cleaning-with-regular-expressions-in.html . It works in the way it takes the RegEx Pattern (htmlTagPattern), and that pattern removes from the specify value field. So If I enter your patern in the code, the result from "CVE-2011-0573,)" is ",)" and not "CVE-2011-0573" ..

Comment: I tried to read that link but understood very little. It seems you cannot combine your existing regex with this. Unfortunately I can only solve the problem which is stated in question and this solution works this much I can assure you (can produce some online regex demo also if you want).

Comment: OK, just asking. The resolution for this question is correct so once thanks again for that :)